# Is there a way for using SFTP tool for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-2017, sftp

I am looking for a tool which helps me to see the folders of a server in Visual Studio 2017 without doing this outside the IDE, actually Notepad++ with the NppFTP plugin can do this and i am taking this as an example, basically you can open a file from the server, edit and upload it automatically upon it is saved.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install SFTP in visual code 2017 by going to extension and type SFTP then installing it. to use the sftp just right click the file and click upload or download base on your needed.

PS:after installing it, place the json file inside your core project. set the hostname, username and password.